# mkdir - read only system

Tags: permissions, chmod, mkdir

Newby here (it has been decades since I have used UNIX.)
Linux (ubuntu) on a chromebook.
From the opening of the command shell I issue *ls* and I get a bunch of directories. I want to create a sub-directory under "/opt" and issue the command *mkdir opt/newdirectory*. Ubuntu responds "Cannot create directory 'opt/newdirectory': Read-only file system." How do I change the permissions so I can create a directory? I have tried all sorts of *chmod* commands but nothing seems to work. It really can't be that hard.

Comment: A file-system being read only means it was mounted that way, or an error has occurred and the system switched it from RW to RO to prevent *further* damage. You can check your logs for details (you didn't give us release details), but I would suggest switching to 'live' media and `fsck` (file system check) your partition for issues if it's a system drive.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I am not ungrateful, but my language skills are limited to English and only a smattering of UNIX. I have tried all the variations of fsck I can imagine and that --help provides but I am no closer to creating a subdirectory. I don't know anything about logs (I am perusing Linux for Dummies) so my learning curve is quite steep. Release Details? This is Chrome 77, I have just installed ubuntu (18?) so I am trying to catch up to all of you who are current (I have been out of the loop for decades.) I will persist.

Comment: I don't know what release of Ubuntu, but to view logs I'd start with `journalctl`  (to view systemd-journal) or `dmesg`  (it'll only show messages for kernel ring buffer of current session; use `man dmesg` to see manual reference page for commands for more info).  There is no Ubuntu 18; Ubuntu releases are *yy.mm* in format, except for (*yearly*) specialist releases such as Ubuntu Core 18 for IoT/appliance devices thus no GUI. `lsb-release -a` will detail release information. You cannot `fsck` a running/mounted system which is why I mentioned a 'live' system (eg. Ubuntu install media).